# Can I avoid a multiple for-loops (without comprehension) or creating separate dictionaries in this Python scenario?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I want to construct a dictionary from which I'll pick data that needs too be inserted into six different new dataframes.

The raw data is currently in two different pandas dataframes (names `base_df` and `stim_df`) with the same layout. 13 columns with headers being the values in the `columns_dict` dictionary and generally ~1200 - 1600 rows. The three functions called (`sum_big_small`, `average_or_median`, and `interpeak_calc`) just return a float from a subset of certain columns i the pandas dataframes (including the numpy.float64 values `nan` or `-inf`)

For the first approach I tried (see below), I didn't really think through. I guess each line of dictionary comprehension would overwrite the last (at least I get an index error when trying to access some of it later)?

```py
import numpy as np

        self.wells = 96
        columns_dict: dict[str, str] = {
            'auc': 'AUC (a.u.)', 'peak_width_10': 'Peak width 10 (ms)', 'peak_width_90': 'Peak width 90 (ms)',
            'slope_20': 'Slope 20 (a.u./ms)', 'slope_80': 'Slope 80 (a.u./ms)', 'decay_time': 'Decay time (ms)',
            'rise_time': 'Rise time (ms)'
        }
        input_dfs = {'base': base_df, 'stim': stim_df}
        average_median: list[str] = ['average', 'median']
        base_stim: list[str] = ['base', 'stim']
        big_small_total: list[str] = ['big', 'small', 'total']

        writing_dict = {i: {'raw': {'number': {k: {'number': [self.sum_big_small(input_dfs[i], well, k) for well in range(1, self.wells + 1)]} for k in big_small_total}}} for i in base_stim}

        writing_dict = {i: {'raw': {j: {k: {column: [self.average_or_median(input_dfs[i], well, j, k, columns_dict[column]) for well in range(1, self.wells + 1)] for column in columns} for k in big_small_total} for j in average_median}} for i in base_stim}

        writing_dict = {i: {'raw': {j: {k: {'interpeak': [self.interpeak_calc(input_dfs[i], well, j, k) for well in range(1, self.wells + 1)]} for k in big_small_total} for j in average_median}} for i in base_stim}

        writing_dict = {'percentage': {'percentage': {j: {k: {column: (100 * (np.array(writing_dict['stim']['raw'][j][k][column]) / np.array(writing_dict['base']['raw'][j][k][column]))) for column in columns_more} for k in big_small_total} for j in average_median}}}
```

But the only way I can then think of doing this is (1) make four different dictionaries, one for each dict comprehension (which would seem less 'neat'), or (2) make everything as for-loops so I can put some of the key variable on the left of the equal; something like (but of course more nested loops):

```
for i in base_stim:
    for j in average_median:
        writing_dict[i]['raw'][j] = SOMETHING
```

But the above definitely seems less elegant. And I think I'd need to set up all the keys before doing the for loops, right?

Is there a better way I can't see, without having to set up the `writing_dict` keys first, and do nested for-loops, and while still adding to the same dictionary?

Extra: I suspect there's also a possibility that I might be better off just staying in pandas, but I definitely couldn't find a way for this. I need to do calculations with subsets of each column, based on the value of two other columns, so the "final" dataframes will end up being 96 rows. In case I'm on the completely wrong track, here's one of the functions I'm using to return values to the list comprehension nested in the dict comprehensions to exemplify what I'm trying to do:

`df['Well number']` is 1-96 (both included), and `df['Big (1) or Small (-1)']` is either 1.0 or -1.0.

```py
    def average_or_median(self, df: pd.DataFrame, well: int, j: str, k: str, column: str) -> any:  # the median returns np.array??
        """
        Takes the DataFrame, and calculates average or median for all values for a given well number,
        either for "big" (=1), for "small" (=-1) or total ("big" + "small"), and returns the calculated value.
        Remember, numpy arrays can return -inf or nan, both floats, when dividing by zero or averaging an empty list.

        Used to get average or median for AUC, Peak Width, Slope, Decay Time, and Rise Time.

        :param df: DatraFrame of either baseline (base_df) or stimulted (stim_df).
        :param well: The well number to process.
        :param j: String, either "average" or "median".
        :param k: String, either "big", "small", or "total".
        :param column: The column header for the data to be processed.
        """
        if k == 'big':
            bs = 1.0
        elif k == 'small':
            bs = -1.0
        else:
            bs = 0
        if abs(bs) == 1.0:
            if j == 'average':
                return np.average(df.loc[(df['Well number'] == well) & (df['Big (1) or Small (-1)'] == bs)][column])
            elif j == 'median':
                return np.median(df.loc[(df['Well number'] == well) & (df['Big (1) or Small (-1)'] == bs)][column])
        else:
            if j == 'average':
                return np.average(df.loc[(df['Well number'] == well)])
            elif j == 'median':
                return np.median(df.loc[(df['Well number'] == well)])
```